# fsockopen with ssl doesn't work from web, but does from cli

Tags: php, fsockopen

I have a script that is pulling data via fsockopen:
$f = fsockopen('ssl://www.url.org', 443, $errno, $errstr);

If I run this from a script on the command line, $f returns a valid resource. If I run it without ssl, it returns a valid resource. If I run it through the web, $f returns boolean false.

What could be preventing this from running successfully via the web?

Comment: run `stream_get_transports` to see what your server is supporting

Comment: ran that function and ssl is included in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work with the server sys admin and find the cause of the problem.

The web server is running PHP 5.6, but when run via SSH, PHP 5.3 was used. The problem with fsockopen on PHP 5.6 was that the service wasn't able to find the global CA certs. We had to update the 5.6 configuration to configure those properly. I guess it was working in 5.3 via the command line because the old configuration was still in place.